# Get value into if statement (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement

I have two IF statements, how can i get value from first into the other one? Next i want to do an insert query to database.

```
if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $eq_l = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "-", $node->nodeValue);
            $eq_l = explode('-',$eq_l);
            $e_home = $eq_l[0];
            $e_away = $eq_l[2];
        }
    }
}

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='bq_plantilla']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $boxes= explode('BANQUILLO',$node->nodeValue);
            $exploded = preg_split('/[\d-\s]\d\s/', $boxes[0]); 
            foreach($exploded as $index => $answer){
                if (!empty($answer) && $index >0 && $index <12){
                    $quit = array("Goal", "YC", "'", "SUBS", "(D.P.)");
                    $quit = str_replace($quitar, "", $answer);
                    $quit = str_replace(":", "*", $quit);
                    $local = preg_replace("/[0-9]{2}/", "", $quit);
                    if (substr_count($local,"*")>0){
                        $loc_camb = explode('*',$local);
                        $local = $loc_camb[0];
                    }
                echo "$local<br>";
                echo "$e_home<br>";
                echo "$e_away<br>";
                }  
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

$e_home and $e_away no returns values.

Thanks!

Comment: is your first `if statement` inside a function ? also , you are changing `$e_home ` and `$e_away ` values inside your loop each time before using them

Comment: It´s all inside in a while loop, $e_home and &e_away are changing, it´s correct, but i dont have function in the program

Comment: your second foreach is changing the values inside the block each time executes , you only may get latest values , and your issues looks like a variable scope mistake or you are assigning null or undefined to them

Comment: I suppose about scope mistake, but i can´t find it, in second foreach that values are not applied. Outside the foreach i get values from $e_home and $e_away

Comment: i have no idea , make sure `nodes` and `elements` have your expected value

Comment: I add `$homes[ ]=$e_home;` and now i can access to value with `$homes[0]` for example, i only need to know in second if, what number i need. Thanks.